# How do I use openalpr in my c++ program in eclipse IDE?

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv, tesseract

I want to use `openalpr` in my C++ project. What must I include to use the API? What libs must be imported in project properties in Eclipse?

Comment: did you already compile openalpr? https://github.com/openalpr/openalpr/wiki/Compilation-instructions-(Windows) what kind of .lib and .dll files are there?

Comment: Have you tried following the official [Integrating the OpenALPR Library](https://github.com/openalpr/openalpr/wiki/Integrating-OpenALPR) guide? Both of your questions are answered there, although not specifically for Eclipse.

Comment: yes....there are .lib file I am using Ubuntu 14.04.I am not able to include the libraries in  for openalpr or for tesseract-ocr.